# Django Amazon S3 Heroku. Connection reset by peer. Remove confirmation on collectstatic script

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3

Ok, so I get the well known error `[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` When I do `collectstatic` on my Django project. The project is on Heroku and I want to send the staticfiles to Amazon S3. I know I have the permissions and I know it works cause the first time I ran the command, it copied 10 files and then reset the conection.

Ok, so I was thinking, maybe I could write a python script that calls `python manage.py collectstatic` on the terminal every two hours, just to check if the connection works. The problem is that `collectstatic` has a confirmation:

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:
```

Is there a way for the script to programatically accept this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```

The Django docs are usually very good, it's right there in the command's `--help` menu:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic --help
...
  --noinput, --no-input
                    Do NOT prompt the user for input of any kind.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this solved it for me:

```
import os

correr = True
for x in range(0, 10):
    respuesta = os.system("python manage.py collectstatic --noinput")
    if not str(respuesta) == "256":
        print "RESPUESTA NO FUE 256, OJALA HAYA FUNCIONADO"
        break
```